# Show year only from datetime using C# Dropdownlist and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to display only the years to a dropdownlist using linq and get the selected value when i click on the search button however, the selected value did not seem to work correctly as it only return the year 2015 as it is the first item in the dropdownlist

Here is my code.

```
public void BindDropDownListYear()
    {
        using (FoodOrderingDBContext db = new FoodOrderingDBContext())
        {
            var query = from o in db.OrderTables
                        group o by (o.OrderedDateTime).Year into og
                        select new { OrderedDateTime = og.Key };
            DropDownListYear.DataSource = query.ToList();
            DropDownListYear.DataTextField = "OrderedDateTime";
            DropDownListYear.DataValueField = "OrderedDateTime";
            DropDownListYear.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What the problem "by only returning year 2015" ? Whats the data?

Comment: Are you calling this method in page load event?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen when i click on my submit button, i have codes to retrieve the selectedvalue of the dropdownlist however, i can only get the first item of the dropdownlist which is 2015. Because apparently, i only have 2 items which is 2015 and 2016

Comment: @AnkitkumarBhatt yes i am calling this method in the page load event.

Comment: Same like ankitkumar asked. Are you reading the selectedvalue before or after you binding this dropdownlist. You should only fill the dropdownlist when the page isnt a 'postback' the data will remain in the viewstate. Google 'ispostback' asp.net. every time you are rebinding your dropdownlist. Your selectedvalue is resetted.

Comment: I also wanted to share the same like Jeroen van Langen said :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to LINQ. It looks like that your problem is about managing your page.

Make sure that you call **BindDropDownListYear**

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    BindDropDownListYear();
}
```